# Strategy to unit test move/copy constructors?

Tags: unit-testing, c++11

I want to write unit tests to test move/copy constructors/assigments of some classes I am writing. I want to make sure that the resources are handled appropriately, that a move ctor is called when I expect it to be called instead of a copy ctor, and vice-versa.

The problem is that I don't want to mess with the class code in order to test this. So, is there a way to know from the test code outside the class, when the move or the copy ctors/assignments were called?

What's a general strategy to unit-test copy/move ctors/assignments?

PD: I am using [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md) unit-testing framework, so please provide an answer that can be implemented in Catch.

Comment: Can you provide a specific class that you want to write tests for?

Comment: @Barry The classes I am working on are too complicated and specific to be useful as examples. But stackoverflow.com is full of examples of move constructors gone wrong. Any of them is a possible scenario where the unit-test should detect the issue.

Comment: So come up with an example. As it stands, this question is too broad.

Comment: Maybe you could wrap your class for testing purposes and test that appropriate (move or copy, as needed) constructor on the wrapper is called.

Answer (score 12):

I have never used Catch so can't provide a working example.

However, I unit test classes with complicated copy/move constructors (e.g. involving deep copies, `std::unique_ptr` etc) by testing the class methods on the moved/copied objects.

For example, if I have a class as follows:

```
// constructor
Foo::Foo(int i) : privateMember(i) {};

// some function that operates on this private member
int Foo::bar() { return privateMember + 5 };
```

I would have a test for the `bar()` method, but then duplicate it for the move, copy etc constructors.  You can easily end up with three or four times the original tests.

I don't expose member variables.  If you do then you may be able to use "is same" test functions (assuming Catch supports this).  For example, making sure a deep copy creates a unique copy (i.e. doesn't point back to the original object).

**Update**

You seem to be more concerned that the correct move or copy constructor/assignment is called.  If you simply want "move assignment" or some other identifier provided I don't know what to suggest.

When I test copy, I make sure I copy the object in my unit test, then call functions that depend on shallow/deep copies of member variables.  This is the same for when I test move.  In some scenarios you can run tests on the original object (e.g. test that a vector instance variable now has a size of zero after the move).

I force a move constructor as follows:

```
Foo foo{};
Foo bar(std::move(foo));
```

I force a move assignment as follows:

```
Foo foo{};
Foo bar{};
bar = std::move(foo);
```

I force a copy constructor as follows:

```
Foo foo{};
Foo bar(foo);
```

I force a copy assignment as follows:

```
Foo foo{};
Foo bar{};
bar = foo;
```

If you really need this you could possibly inherit from some debug virtual class that exposes a enum class field.  In your debug build the field gets populated with an appropriate enum value (MoveConstructor).  This field is exposed so you can test it after a copy/move.  Make sure that you populate it in your copy/move constructors/assignment methods.

Comment: I am actually interested in testing that move moves, while copy copies. That is, I am sure move and copy both create exact copies, which pass all my "is same" tests. What I want is to test the efficiency. That is, I want to make sure that moves are being made instead of copies when I expect them to be.

Comment: @becko - I have updated the answer.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Aren't `Foo foo();` and `Foo bar();` function declarations?